# get parent node/tag of a specific node/tag in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to delete a specific xml tag using c# but the problem is, that tag may be located in different parent tags.

So I need to search for that specific tag and get its parent tag then delete it.

This is my xml file

```
<PublisherInfo>
    <PublisherName value="1">Askquestionzero Publisher</PublisherName>
    <PublisherLocation>Ph</PublisherLocation>
    <PublisherImprintName>Askquestionzero</PublisherImprintName>
    <PublisherLogo>
      <Tada>Remove this value and its content</Tada>
    </PublisherLogo>
    <PublisherURL>Askquestionzero.com</PublisherURL>
</PublisherInfo>
```

and this is my code

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\askquestion.xml");
XmlNode nodeToDelete = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/PublisherInfo/PublisherLogo/Tada");
if (nodeToDelete != null)
{
    nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete);
}
Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
```

The code works but I need to specify its parent tag. So how loop through the xml file and if the `Tada` tag is found, get its parent tag then delete it.

expected output:

```
<PublisherInfo>
    <PublisherName value="1">Askquestionzero Publisher</PublisherName>
    <PublisherLocation>Ph</PublisherLocation>
    <PublisherImprintName>Askquestionzero</PublisherImprintName>
    <PublisherLogo>
    </PublisherLogo>
    <PublisherURL>Askquestionzero.com</PublisherURL>
</PublisherInfo>
```

Another question:

I need also to change the node of a xml file. The file is the same as above.

Here is the code for changing the xml node/tag name. But it keeps its attribute. What I want it to change its tag name and delete its attribute.

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\askquestion.xml");
Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
XmlElement element = (XmlElement)xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("PublisherName")[0];
XmlElement renamedElement = (XmlElement)RenameNode(element, null, "new-element");
Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
public static XmlNode RenameNode(XmlNode node, string namespaceUri, string qualifiedName)
{
    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        XmlElement oldElement = (XmlElement)node;
        XmlElement newElement = node.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(qualifiedName, namespaceUri);
        while (oldElement.HasAttributes)
        {
        newElement.SetAttributeNode(oldElement.RemoveAttributeNode(oldElement.Attributes[0]));
        }
        while (oldElement.HasChildNodes)
        {
            newElement.AppendChild(oldElement.FirstChild);
        }
        if (oldElement.ParentNode != null)
        {
            oldElement.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newElement, oldElement);
        }
        return newElement;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The output of the code above:

```
<new-element value="1">Askquestionzero Publisher</new-element>
```

Desired output:

```
<new-element>Askquestionzero Publisher</new-element>
```

Comment: You just want to remove `Tada` element or including parent element? It would help if you include your expected output.

Comment: the question is updated. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using `XDocument`, using `Linq` to `Xml` you could just locate the element and call `Remove` as shown.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

    doc.Descendants("Tada")
        .First()
        .Remove();
```

Regarding other question, where you want remove the attribute you could use same logic (something like this).

```
    doc.Descendants("new-element")
        .Select(e=>e.Attribute("value"))
        .Remove();
```

Since you want to change `TagName`, I prefer adding new element and removing existing element (as mentioned in the comments). Below code removes `PublisherName` element which has `value` as one of the attributes.

```
    var elements=doc.Descendants("PublisherName")
        .Where(e=>e.Attribute("value") != null);

    foreach(var element in elements)
    {
        element.Parent.Add(new XElement("new-element", (string)element.Value));
    }
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cxwQYK)

Comment: can you give me the code for changing the element name to a new one? thank you. without getting its attribute. and leaving the attribute untoched? thank you. and i think i need to learn linq

Comment: I don't prefer changing the element name, rather I would add new element and remove existing element.

Comment: how can i do that sir? can you give me an example? on how to remove an element name and add a new one. in the location of the element removed? thank you. ill mark as checked the question after i solve this problem. thank you

Comment: i have another question sir. when i run the code to remove the element name. it works, but in only remove the first node name "tada" and the next node name "tada" is untoched. how can i do that? do i need to read the xml file and check how many occurence of that node name "tada" and loop it with the count of the occurence of tada. or do you have better idea? thank you

Comment: Because we are using `First`, if you want to remove all `tada` tags remove this `First` extension method. That cause all the elements of tada to be removed.

Comment: and when i run the last example you gave me sir. i received an error. but when i run on the web site. it works. why?
this is the output error: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Dump' and no extension method 'Dump' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Don't use `Dump` in real code (remove it). Basically it dumps everything in an editor and generally used for quick presentation.

Comment: another question sir. thank you for your patience. the last example you gave me also change the location of the tag, what i need sir is it. when we remove the tag. the new tag location is in the location of the tag removed. thanks

Comment: In general position doesn't matter in `Xml` unless some business demands it.

Comment: in the program im creating sir. i need the position of the xml properly.